# Error al generar jar en grandle

Tags: java, gradle

que tal, tengo un pequeño a grande problema, tengo la siguiente situación:

Quiero generar un jar con las dependencias descargadas dentro del mismo, pero no consigo que funcione, aquí mi build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'

    //Para el TLS
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.59'
    //Para el log
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2'
    testCompile ("org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.4.10") {
        exclude module : 'groovy-all' //localGroovy and spock groovy will probably conflict. Both are 2.x, we're good.
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.5"
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from destinationDir
}
```

Vi las siguientes páginas intentandolo:

[UNO](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/)
[DOS](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571)
[TRES](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)
[CUATRO](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)
[CINCO](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin)
[SEIS](https://newfivefour.com/gradle-hello-world-java-fat-jar.html)
[SIETE](http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar)

Tengo configurada la variable de entorno de gradle con la versión 3.5.

Gracias.

Aquí el error:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(DefaultToolingClient.java:106)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultModelRequest.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRequest.java:79)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$1.get(BaseModelRepository.java:95)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeAndWait(BaseModelRepository.java:163)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.access$000(BaseModelRepository.java:41)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$2.call(BaseModelRepository.java:121)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.getFromCache(BaseModelRepository.java:138)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:117)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:88)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.fetchEclipseGradleBuild(DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleBuild(DefaultModelProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Httpstls'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
```

Cabe señalar que he cambiado la versión de gradle e intente con cada ejemplo que puse, las versiones que use de gradle fueron: 2.14, 3.5, 4.3.1 y 4.4.1

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39167691/5587982) y verifica que tienes todo actualizado: Gradle y Eclipse.

Comment: Lo tengo todo actualizado. Gracias.